# Parse Json from client side when object contains single values and objects

Tags: c#, json

How to parse JSON object witch contains single values and objects? JSON example:

```
[
  "url here",
  "url here",
  "url here",
  "url here",
  "url here",
  {"fileName":"Agurkai.jpg","fileSize":188518},
  {"fileName":"destinations7.jpg","fileSize":231898},
  {"fileName":"Poras.jpg","fileSize":30750}
]
```

Comment: You could deserialize it to a list of object if that helps you... And yes, it is a valid JSON. So basically JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json). That is if you're using json.net.

Comment: What serializer are you using?  [tag:json.net]?  [tag:javascriptserializer], [tag:datacontractjsonserialize] or something else?

Comment: Why is your clientside app sending such badly formatted data.Sensibly, an Array of things should all be the same structure

Comment: Sorry, should be JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(json)

Comment: You can use dynamic. JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

Comment: Thank you @PrebenHuybrechts, it works fine